# Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <html> in <div>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

Нужна помощь
Перенес html на next.js, полетели ошибки:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <html> in <div>.
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

Это не все ошибки, но остальные выходят из этих.

Вот мой код:

````
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Script from 'next/script'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('Sending')

    let data = {
        name,
        email,
        message
    }

    fetch('/api/contact', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log('Response received')
        if (res.status === 200) {
            console.log('Response succeeded!')
            setSubmitted(true) 
            setName('1')
            setEmail('2')
            setMessage('3')
        }
    })
  }

  return (
    <html lang="ru">
      <Head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Квадратные Уравнения</title>
</Head>
<body>
    <header className="header">
        <nav className="header-nav">
            <ul className="header-menu">
                <li className="header-menu-item menu-logo"><a href="index.js"><img src='/logo.svg' alt="#" className="logo"/></a></li>
                <li className="header-menu-item"><a href="pages/theory.js" className="header-menu-link">\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\)</a></li>
                <li className="header-menu-item"><a href="pages/practice.js" className="header-menu-link">Практика</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main className="main">
        <div className="content">
            <section className="types-header-sect">
                <h2 className="types-header"></h2>
            </section>
            <section className="types">
                <a className="type" href='pages/mnos.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/videl.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/formulas.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/viet.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/perebros.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/chastn.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/graph.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/cirkul.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/nomo.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
                <a className="type" href='pages/geom.js'>
                    <h4 className="type-name"></h4>
                    <p className="type-text"></p>
                </a>
            </section>
        </div>
      < form className={styles.main} >
          < label htmlFor='name'>Name</label>
          < input type='text' onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} name='name' className={styles.inputField} />
          <br />
          < label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
          < input type='email' onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} name='email' className={styles.inputField} />
          <br />
          < label htmlFor='message'>Message</label>
          < input type='text' onChange={(e)=>{setMessage(e.target.value)}} name='message' className={styles.inputField} />
          <br />
          < input type='submit' onClick={(e)=>{handleSubmit(e)}}/>
      </form >
      </main>
</body>
</html>
  )
}```
````

Comment: В HTML который вы получаете, корневой тег HTML обернут в тег div, о чем собственно и ошибка **matching <html> in <div>** Смотрите, что вы куда положили, что генериться на сервере, что приходит клиенту...

Answer (score 1):

Я смог разобраться. Какой то из компонентов создавал теги html, div и body, внутри которых уже размещал мой код. Таким образом возникали повторения тегов и странные  вложения. Я убрал у себя html и body, заменив их на div-ы и проблема исправилась